# How do I get RDS instance id for an Elastic Beanstalk environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'd like to write a script that snapshots and restores the RDS database associated with my Elastic Beanstalk environment. How can I get the RDS instance id which I'll be plugging into the `aws rds create-db-snapshot` and `aws rds restore-db-instance-from-db-snapshot` commands?

I know that it can be seen in the Configuration tab in the web interface, but I wanted to get it using a command executed in the shell.

Answer (score 1):

While you can configure an RDS instance when you configure an Elastic Beanstalk application, they are not really tied together.  They can both run in a VPC but that's the only real grouping per se.  You could easily use the RDS for something else too.

You will likely want to use something like `aws rds describe-db-instances` to get the RDS instance information coupled with an instance name (i.e. application1-ebs-rds) to allow you to locate the RDS.

Comment: thanks for confirming my intuition that they both run in a vpc

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way that I've found involves the following steps

1. SSH into your instance with `$ eb ssh {environment-id}`
2. Run the following command from the SSH terminal to get the RDS instance id:

   `$ sudo /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment --output YAML | grep RDS_HOSTNAME | sed -n "s/^RDS_HOSTNAME: \([a-z0-9]*\).*$/\1/p"`

The above command gets all the available environment variables, including the special ones that start with `RDS_`, greps for the `RDS_HOSTNAME` variable, and then extracts the value you need with `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a history of event this way...

```
aws elasticbeanstalk describe-events --environment-name your_environment_name
```

One of the events in your history should include the db-instance-identifier...

```
{
    "ApplicationName": "some-app", 
    "EnvironmentName": "some-env", 
    "Severity": "INFO", 
    "RequestId": "some-ref-id", 
    "Message": "Created RDS database named: some-db-instance-identifier", 
    "EventDate": "2017-01-30T23:23:37.734Z"
},
```

Then you can take that message string and get the DB Instance Identifier to use here...

```
aws rds create-db-snapshot --db-instance-identifier some-db-instance-identifier --db-snapshot-identifier name-of-snapshot
```

It's a bit of work. :)

Comment: According to the docs, this command only saves events up to 6 weeks back, meaning that if the environment was created more than 6 weeks ago you will probably not find this event